# Select records with number in a string

Tags: t-sql

I have a table [CLIData] containing phone numbers and corresponding customers:

```
Number       Customer
01234567890  GeoffLtd
01234567891  FredLtd
01234567892  1JimLtd
01234567893  21DaveLtd
01234567894  297AhmedLtd
01234567895  FrankLtd
```

The customers that start with a numeric are part of Group1, customers that start with an alphabetic are part of Group2.

I am looking to create a query that will insert into another table [CustomerData] as below:

```
Number       Group
01234567890  Group2
01234567891  Group2
01234567892  Group1
01234567893  Group1
01234567894  Group1
01234567895  Group2
```

Can someone help me with the WHERE on this? Is there a simple way to query where 1st character is numeric?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO CustomerData(Number, [Group])
SELECT  Number, 
        CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Customer, 1, 1)) = 1
            THEN 'GROUP1'
            ELSE 'GROUP2'
        END [GROUP]
FROM    CLIData
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19ef1/1)

Comment: Poifect! I'd never come across "ISNUMERIC" before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    * 
    ,gr = case when patindex('[0-9]%',customer)>0 THEN 'Group1' else 'Group2' end
from (
    select '01234567890' as number,'GeoffLtd' as customer union all
    select '01234567891','FredLtd' union all
    select '01234567892','1JimLtd' union all
    select '01234567893','21DaveLtd' union all
    select '01234567894','297AhmedLtd' union all
    select '01234567895','FrankLtd'
) x
```